# How to get UITableviewcell value on click on button?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to get UITableviewCell value on click of update button. When user press on update button then i want to fetch first cell(name) and second cell(oil cost) value. Please help me.

Comment: Admittedly I know nothing about developing for ios, but I have no clue what you are on about. What have you got/tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:(
Try below code,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0];
UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString* name = cell1.textLabel.text;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 1 inSection: 0];
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString* oilcost = cell2.textLabel.text;
```

Comment: I'm try above example and get the uitextfield text. But the text is not correct text field return text old not new(user currently enter text).

Comment: let me know your code what you have tried or how you have done